# Help identifying this orchestral work

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

I heard [this piece](https://clyp.it/kbxjldef) on public radio a few years ago and I haven't been able to track it down. It sounds a bit like Elgar, but I haven't found any pieces that match it.

Comment: Do you have an alternative method of sharing the piece of music besides the link you provided?

Comment: I guess, you are right with the period. My best guess is a dance suite for string orchestra, but neither Holst St. Paul Suite nor Janacek, Danses Lachiennes or Idylle matched.

Comment: Lately I've been wondering if it's Walton, since occasionally his work can sound like Elgar, but I still haven't been able to track it down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the fourth movement (*Molto vivace*) of the *Serenade for strings in F major* (Opus 6) by Felix Weingartner.

The extract corresponding to your audio file can be heard [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R1Z5Y2zIJ9U&t=10m0s).

The names of the other movements can be found [here](https://repertoire-explorer.musikmph.de/en/product/weingartner-felix-8/).

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I've been looking for this for about 7 years now, and I'd all but given up. Did you just happen to know the piece, or did you use an app of some kind?

Comment: @Richard I used acrcloud.